# How to get Parts Category from model Revit 2022 using forge API

Tags: javascript, api, autodesk-forge, revit-api, forge

I'm trying extract all elements from parts category from revit metadata using Model Derivate API but I can't find any.
How can I get part category from revit metadata?
[metadata look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDOkm.png)

Answer (score 0):

When using this endpoint `GET {urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties`, you get all the properties of objects.

To get **categories**, you should use this endpoint `GET {urn}/metadata/{guid}` which gives you the hierarchy tree of all objects in the scene.

**Revit** files usually has this structure **categories** / **families** / **types** / **instances**, so if you parse the tree, you can easily get all objects for a given **category**.